# When branching, should defects be cloned?

Tags: git, tfs, jira, bug-tracking

Looking for a consensus on best practice here.  We use both TFS and Jira - not sure if implementation differs between the two, but if we generalize the issue tracking system, the question is:

If you have an unresolved defect in your master branch, and you branch / fork into a long lived branch, do you clone that known defect against the new long lived branch?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a defect or any issue really is to be able to track the work associated with it - who does the work, how long did it take, what other information was needed.

I recommend keeping a single place for most of the information about the defect. Then created linked issues or subtasks (Jira) to record that work needs to be done for the long-lived branch. If you clone the defect, you will end up trying to gather information from multiple places, which is extra work.